# Bundle install doesnt install gem in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, gemfile

I am typing the following command:

```
rake -RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
```

In the home directory of my rails app on my production server and I get the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

This is strange because I know that pg is in my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'paperclip'
  gem 'will_paginate'
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

And when I run `bundle install` from that directory I get the following output (pg is not on it.):

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.3.6)
Using activesupport (3.2.8)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.8)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.3)
Using actionpack (3.2.8)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.8)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
Using activerecord (3.2.8)
Using activeresource (3.2.8)
Using cocaine (0.2.1)
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.7.5)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.16.0)
Using railties (3.2.8)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0)
Using warden (1.2.1)
Using devise (2.1.2)
Using haml (3.1.7)
Using haml-rails (0.3.4)
Using jquery-rails (2.1.1)
Using paperclip (3.1.2)
Using bundler (1.2.1)
Using rails (3.2.8)
Using sass (3.2.1)
Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
Using uglifier (1.2.7)
Using will_paginate (3.0.3)
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /usr/local/lib
```

And my Gemfile.lock if it's relevant (pg is listed as a dependency only):

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.3)
    activemodel (3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
    activesupport (3.2.8)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)
    builder (3.0.0)
    capistrano (2.12.0)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    cocaine (0.2.1)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
    devise (2.1.2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    haml (3.1.7)
    haml-rails (0.3.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      haml (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
    highline (1.6.13)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.1.1)
      railties (>= 3.1.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.5)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.3.6)
    net-scp (1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    net-sftp (2.0.5)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.9)
    net-ssh (2.5.2)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    paperclip (3.1.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    pg (0.14.0-x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.8)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      activerecord (= 3.2.8)
      activeresource (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.8)
    railties (3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.1)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thor (0.16.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.2.7)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  capistrano
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  devise
  haml-rails
  jquery-rails
  paperclip
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.8)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  will_paginate
```

Contents of .bundle/config:

```
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
BUNDLE_PATH: /usr/local/lib/
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
```

I am using 
- rails 3.2.8
- ruby 1.9.3 
- rvm 1.16.5

Can anyone offer an explanation as to why bundle install is not installing all the gems listed in my Gemfile?

Comment: you need to install postgresql separately... what is your operation system? take a look here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf5jPUJAeU4

Comment: What are the contents of your `.bundle/config` file?

Comment: Thanks, but I already have postgresql installes `which psql` gives `/usr/bin/psql` and `psql --version` gives `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.6`. Is there something special I have to do to get it working for rails (on Debian install)?

Comment: Contents of .bundle/config have been added above.

Comment: It's strange, you speak about `debian` install, but your Gemfile.lock shows a windows build platform (`x86-mingw32`).

Comment: The `DEPENDENCIES` section of `Gemfile.lock` is the list of gems you explicitly require as dependencies.

Comment: My deployment server is Debian; my development machine is Windows.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem like yours. 'pg' is in gem query, but bundle just wont install 'pg'. So every time is gives error "Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile." Have you solved this problem now? Would you post a detailed solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through some detective work I found out the following factors contributed to my problem:

1) I was developing on a Windows machine that installed the windows-specific version of the gem pg: (0.14.0-x86-mingw32).

2) This was then added to my Gemfile.lock and consequently my repo that capistrano then used to install my app on a Debian box with; pg was listed as a dependency, only.

3) capistrano was running bundler with the "--deployment" flag, which requires your Gemfile.lock to be up-to-date and accurate.

How I resolved the problem was removed the "--deployment" flag from capistrano with the following variable definition in deploy.rb:

```
set :bundle_flags, "--quiet"

require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

And ran the `cap deploy:update` again.

Still working on a way to have the Gemfile.lock reflect that pg should be installed on the production environment, while pg should be installed on the development machine so I can include the --deployment option back into the deployment task.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use bundler to execute rake:

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Thanks, but this yields the same error message. Can you please explain the difference between running the rake task with and without the bundle command? I've never been clear on this. Is it just that it runs the rake task with the gemset defined in the bundle?

Comment: It ensures that the loaded gems are those declared in the gemfile. Could you post the output of `bundle show pg` ?

Comment: ` Could not find gem 'pg' in the current bundle.`

Comment: put the `gem "pg"` out of the block. Search all your project for references to `mingw`. Remove the `.bundle` directory and let the system host your gems.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean when you say let the system host your gems?

Answer (score 1):

For the database.yml

it should be

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: utf8
    database: xxx
    host: localhost
    username: username
    password: pw
```

the adapter for postgresql is postgresql

And for the gem file, make sure pg is there
and you don't need a block if it exist in both development and production

Comment: database.yml already looks like this and Gemfile definitely contains 'pg' already.